# Is there a simple way to synch up two AWS RDS Mysql Instances?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have two databases. One for development and one for production. The production database has been used for while now and we need to start development of new features, so we obviously want to try out everything in the development DB. These are two RDS MySQL instances which are configured exactly the same.

My question is: is there a simple way where I can make the development DB have the same information as the production DB? So that I can start developing using realistic info?

I obviously can dump and upload, but I thought there might be a more elegant way

Answer (score 1):

Check out [**AWS Database Migration Service (DMS)**](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) - that's what you need. It can run continuously, replicating Prod to Dev. Or you can run it manually from time to time, but be aware that if you use the Dev DB the subsequent sync may fail due to conflicts.

Another possible option is to create a **[Read Replica](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/)** for your Prod database, let it sync, and then *disconnect and promote* to be the Dev DB.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The second option is what I usually do. But since it meand deleteing the currnet DB and then doing the recreation, it's kind of a pain. Did not know about the first, though. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

MLu's answer is great to solve the problem the way you've asked. DMS is fairly easy to get working, and works well. It can do on-off or ongoing migrations. Read replicas are also a good solution. However, I don't know if what you're planning is a good idea.

Generally putting production data into development environments is a Very Bad Idea. It means your production data is in an environment which usually isn't protected as well as production, and many more people such as developers have access to production data. I suggest that you not do this unless your data is effectively public or you can put other controls in place to ensure data security.

A better option is to write custom code that pulls from the production database, inserts random data, masks fields, and such. There's some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629698/how-to-migrate-data-from-production-to-develop-but-scramble-sensitive-data). There might be a product or service that makes this easier, searching the internet might find something to make it easier.

Comment: Thank you, but the environment shared by the development data and production data is effectively the same. So same security measures and the our team is just me and one other developer and he is wrinting front end so he will get access to the data eventually.  Thank yo for your suggestions though.

Comment: Ok. I'll leave this answer here because it is relevant to many people considering doing this.